# How to make CSS Column Design quickly?

Tags: css, xhtml

I've tried all other Blueprint, 960 etc . I want make custom framework for custom width and gutters which should be modify for any width or spacing between boxes.
I need the best optimize and quick way to make layout. Want to make a reusable framework/method/patteren in css.

**For examples:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [fivetechnology.com](http://www.fivetechnology.com/images/blog/hunting_wireframe1.jpg))</sub>

**Edit:**
By now i found this article useful http://www.cssnewbie.com/build-custom-frameworks/
would like to know others views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you genuinely understand html and css, these sorts of things literally fall together in about five minutes with notepad.

They're boxes...

...After I said this, I had to see if I was really fast enough to do that in notepad. I'm high, I have nothing better to do, and I figure I should be able to back what I say up.

```
I almost got too lazy, but then I just committed, cause it would only
be five minutes, right? 

Started at:
```

> Honor system here I guess, everything
>   between this time and the next time
>   was all that I typed between those two
>   times. After I finished I copied it
>   out into coda, saved it to see that it
>   worked (it did), fixed the formatting
>   for readability, and pasted it back
>   in. Yes I really put the font family
>   and colors in, I don't know why. I
>   figured why not?

```
2:35:17

<html>
<head>
<title>Speed Challenge Impromptu</title>
</head>
<style>
 body {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
 }
 #wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  background: #222;
 }
 #header {
  height: 160px;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
 }
 #menu {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #555;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
 }
 #content {
  height: 800px;
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 #footer {
  height: 25px;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
 }
</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header">
 </div>
 <div id="menu">

 </div>
 <div id="content">

 </div>
 <div id="footer">

 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

2:41:52
```

[Not bad for being totally unprepared in a bit over six minutes.](http://www.sneakyness.com/speed.png) I assure you I was rather slow in typing and thinking, I wouldn't doubt a sub two minute time. All the colors were guessed as were the sizes. It's not ideal for a production website, but it's great to figure out what's going where initially.

I didn't have columns in mine, you can basically copy those boxes inside of themselves styling-wise and do quite a lot row-wise. Fixed widths and floating rights would get the job done for columns.

[This is what a finished version could look like.](http://artemis.sneakyness.com/OOFS/) Obviously taking much longer than five minutes, but still not bad.

Comment: u made simplest structure. i'm not talking about how to make simple css layout

Comment: @Jitendra: If you are capable of comprehending what happened above, then you would understand what I said afterwards, and that you can easily add columns by floating fixed-width columns to the right.

Answer (score 1):

The kinds of layouts you have shown makes me feel that [960 grid system](http://960.gs/) might be fit for that.

Comment: That's like complaining about having to use pixels as a screen unit of measurement. 960 is awesome, it helps people like you make quite well thought out and presented layouts. You're obviously above it though.

Answer (score 0):

If there was a "best way" to build a CSS framework, then one of the existing products would either already be using it, or whoever knew it would be building one right now.

Unfortunately, since you've tried all the products and they don't work for you, I don't think you're going to have much luck.  No one can just tell you the "best way" to build a framework.  It's like asking what the "best way to build a car" would be.  It's a pretty broad subject.

If you have specific questions relate to the technical aspects of framework building, someone can probably give you a hand.

Comment: By now i found this article useful http://www.cssnewbie.com/build-custom-frameworks/

Comment: I suppose that's a start, but it's pretty brazen to call nine CSS classes a framework.

Comment: My purpose is just to make my layout development process faster , not making a framework.why i use word "Framework" bcoz people understand easily what i'm asking

Comment: Bro if you're trying to make things faster, you can't get much faster than SIX MINUTES BY HAND UNPREPARED, STONED AT 3AM. Actually I'd like to see you try that, buddy.

Comment: @Sneakyness - u r not getting my point. What you have made i can make faster than you. i've prebuilt templates. question is not not about how fast we can make layout only. I was asking to make group of classes to make grid u need to see this article. http://www.cssnewbie.com/build-custom-frameworks/

Comment: You can't say that without a screencast to back it up. I have prebuilt templates too, we all do. If you have all these things, why don't you make it yourself? You're supposedly so awesome. Go learn english while you're at it.

Comment: I think u haven't see this article http://www.cssnewbie.com/build-custom-frameworks/ yet. I found my answer here. and already added in question.

Comment: No I have. I'm waiting for your screencast to see you do what I did in <6 minutes.

Comment: man i use this technique http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/how-i-can-code-twice-as-fast-as-you/. I'm not thinking to make screencast. you win